# ListView always deletes last row from CustomAdaptor

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem, custom-adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a ListView in AlertDialog which contains more button on each row & it will popup a list with delete option. When I click on delete option, its deleting the last item. In CustomAdaptor I tried a notifyDataSetChanged() after deleting item from ArrayList. Here it always deletes the last item irrespective of item position.

**CustomAdaptor Code**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;
List<String> lrowItems ;
ArrayList<String> listItems;
String className;
CalHelper calHelper;
Settings settings;
LayoutInflater inflter;
public CustomAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<String> listItems) {
    this.context = applicationContext;
    this.listItems = listItems;
    this.className = context.getClass().getSimpleName();
    this.calHelper  = new CalHelper(applicationContext);
    this.settings  = new Settings(applicationContext);
    inflter = (LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext));
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(listItems != null) {
        return listItems.size();
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return listItems.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

//With following overrides Prevent listview item will not mix randomly
//and convertView provided is of the appropriate type.
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    if(getCount() > 0){ //for no records in returning view
        return getCount();
    }else{
        return super.getViewTypeCount();
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}

/* private view holder class for holding calculation history*/
private class HistoryViewHolder {
    TextView more;
    TextView expression;
    TextView result;
    TextView shortNote;
    TextView expTime;
}

/* private view holder class for holding GST calculations history*/
private class GstHistoryViewHolder {
    TextView amount;
    TextView gst;
    TextView total;
    TextView expTime;
    ImageView share;
}

/* private view holder class */
private class BMIViewHolder {
    TextView bmiScore;
    TextView bmiDate;
    TextView bmiWeight;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    //final int pos = position;
    if(className.equals("MainActivity")) {
        final HistoryViewHolder holder = new HistoryViewHolder();
        final String expString = listItems.get(position);
        final String expre = expString.substring(0, expString.indexOf(":"));
        final String expreTime = expString.substring(expString.indexOf(":") + 1, expString.length());
        final String result = expre.substring(expre.indexOf("=")+1);
        String timePattern = calHelper.calHistoryTimePattern(expreTime);
        SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(timePattern);

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
            holder.more = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.more);
            holder.expression = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expression);
            holder.result = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result);
            holder.shortNote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shortNote);
            holder.expTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expTime);
            holder.expression.setText(expre.substring(0, expre.indexOf("=")));
            holder.result.setText(result);
            String time = localDateFormat.format(new Date(expreTime));
            holder.expTime.setText(time);
            holder.shortNote.setText(settings.getHistoryNote(context,expString));

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            final TextView btnMore = (TextView) holder.more;
            btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    showPopup(v, position, expString, expre, expreTime, holder.shortNote);
                }
            });

        }
    }


    return convertView;
}


public void showPopup(View v, final int position, final String expString, final String expression, final String expTime, final TextView shortNote) {
    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, v);

    //truncate title with ellipsis for more characters
    final String noteTitle = expression.length()>10? expression.substring(0, 10) + "..." : expression;
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.history_menu, popup.getMenu());
    //registering popup with OnMenuItemClickListener
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
            int itenId = item.getItemId();
            switch (itenId){
                case R.id.mnuInsertExpression:
                    //some code here
                break;
                case R.id.mnuHisNote:
                    //some code here                        
                    break;
                case  R.id.mnuCopyHisRecord:
                    calHelper.copyToClipboard(expression);
                    break;
                case R.id.mnuShareHisRecord:
                    calHelper.shareText(expression);
                    break;
                case  R.id.mnuDeleteHisRecord:  //This is where I am deleting item
                    System.out.println("Pos:"+position);
                      listItems.remove(position);
                      notifyDataSetChanged();
                    Collections.reverse(listItems); //sort descending by time again
                    settings.clearSharedPre(context,expString); //remove note attached to this expression from ShredPref
                    settings.saveArrayList(context, listItems, "EXP_HISTORY");
                    intent.putExtra("HISTORY_RECORD_DELETED", true);
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Record removed from history", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    context.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
    popup.show();
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this getView():

```
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            HistoryViewHolder holder;
            if(className.equals("MainActivity")) {
                final String expString = listItems.get(position);
                final String expre = expString.substring(0, expString.indexOf(":"));
                final String expreTime = expString.substring(expString.indexOf(":") + 1, expString.length());
                final String result = expre.substring(expre.indexOf("=")+1);
                String timePattern = calHelper.calHistoryTimePattern(expreTime);
                SimpleDateFormat localDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(timePattern);

                if (convertView == null) {
                    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_row, null);
                    holder = new HistoryViewHolder();
                    holder.more = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.more);
                    holder.expression = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expression);
                    holder.result = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.result);
                    holder.shortNote = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.shortNote);
                    holder.expTime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.expTime);

                    holder.more.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int pos = (int) v.getTag();
                            showPopup(v, pos, expString, expre, expreTime, holder.shortNote);
                        }
                    });
                }else{
                    holder = (HistoryViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
                }
                holder.expression.setText(expre.substring(0, expre.indexOf("=")));
                holder.result.setText(result);
                String time = localDateFormat.format(new Date(expreTime));
                holder.expTime.setText(time);
                holder.shortNote.setText(settings.getHistoryNote(context, expString));
                holder.more.setTag(position);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }
            return convertView;
        }
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Great!! It works. holder.more.setOnClickListene gives syntax error, I replaced it with original btnMore.setOnClickListener but rest all is as per the way you mentioned. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using the position of the getView parameter, that will always be whatever the last index is at the time you go to use it.

Instead you need to add that position to the view, possibly in your convertView is what I usually do (the tag can be anything you want), do `convertView.setTag(position)` in your getView method as you are creating each items view, and then in your delete method within showpopup you can do `(int)view.getTag()` to get the position to remove from your dataset.

Comment: No effect using setTag and getTag. I am getting correct position of view but it deletes last item only.  I am showing the ListView in AlertDalog, is that make any difference in normal listview/adaptor functioning.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `postion` to the `button` using `setTag()` and get the `position` when passing it to `showPopup()` using `getTag()`. You can do the following.

```
 // ....
 final TextView btnMore = (TextView) holder.more;
 btnMore.setTag(position); // here add the position to the button using setTag().
 btnMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         // here you can get position your button using v.getTag().
         int pos = (int) v.getTag();
         showPopup(v, pos, expString, expre, expreTime, holder.shortNote);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is again deleting the last item.